# Is it possible to hide form from non-registered users?

Tags: contact-form-7

I need to hide form with some shortcode `[contact-form-7 id="3080"]` from non-registered users in WordPress.
So i've tried to use inserted tags like this '[client][contact-form-7 id="3080"][/client]' and it doesn't work.

with this php code

```
 function access_check_shortcode( $attr, $content = null ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'capability' => 'read' ), $attr ) );

    if ( current_user_can( $capability ) && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
        return $content;

    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'access', 'access_check_shortcode' );
```

This one isn't interesting, cause i need to show it inside the template

```
<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you willing/able to install third party plugins? If so, you might want to check out either or both of these:

1. Hide This (https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-this/)
2. Eyes Only (https://bs.wordpress.org/plugins/eyes-only-user-access-shortcode/)

Both of these work by enabling shortcode that can be wrapped around specific content. I believe both have options to how only to logged-in users.

Comment: Try this, but wordpress don't want to do my shortcodes inside [hide][/hide]